# what is wrong with this code?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to read a text file, query the database table with that name, and store that table's data in another table. So far I have written this code but I don't know why it's not working.

```
foreach ($lindb as $namedb) { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ntable WHERE name =" .$namedb. ""; 
    $result  = mysql_query($query);
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO ndtable (name,details,address,login,country) VALUES (\"".$r["name"]."\", \"".$r["details"]."\", \"".$r["address"]."\", \"".$r["login"]."\", \"".$r["country"]."\")";    
        mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's sometimes good to display mysql error after a query: `mysql_error()` when debugging

Comment: Although the bug is related to an incorrectly formatted SQL statement, please don't say "its not working", because you aren't actually giving anyone enough information to reasonably help you. Always post the actual error message instead, see http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code

Answer (score 3):

You don't have quotes around $namedb

ie. `SELECT * FROM ntable WHERE name =" .$namedb. "";` should be `SELECT * FROM ntable WHERE name ='" .$namedb. "'";`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a [SELECT INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) would be the better choice... and please post the error so we are able to help...